# Grunt Serve | connect:livereload Port 9000 already in use

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I've used Yeoman to build an angular application using bower and grunt. Running grunt serve gives me this error:

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Fatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process.
```

I have another process using port 9000 so I would like to just change the port for Grunt. I've tried to change the port in my Gruntfile, but I continue to get the same error. Here is the grunt sever settings from Gruntfile.js

```
 connect: {
     options: {
        port: 9002,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
  },
```

Answer (score 10):

Find the process id that is using the port:

```
sudo lsof -i :3000
```

Kill it:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```